# Calculate rolling incremental of properties from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, lodash

I have an array of objects of this structure

```
- day
- dimension
- sub-dimension
  ...
- sub-sub-dimension
- measure1, measure2,...
```

and want to convert into this structure to feed into a dashboard template, with the "diff" is DoD difference.

```
- day
- dimension
- sub-dimension
  ...
- sub-sub-dimension
- measure1: [value,#diff,%diff]
- measure2: [value,#diff,%diff]
  ...
```

My best logic so far is

- Loop through the data and group by every value combinations of `dimensionList`.
- Populate an array of values for each measure combination in the `measureList` with all days.
- Calculate rolling difference for each measure.
- Update back to the original data.

My best attemp failed at the first step at generating the array for each combinations and my logic isn't neat as well. Hope someone could help, it's okay to use packages.

```js
    const dimensionList = ["city","category"];
    const measureList = ["order","buyer","gmv"];
    const newData = [];
    measureList.forEach(measure => {
      newData.push(
        {
          measure: measure,
          values: _.chain(data)
                   .groupBy(data,item => dimensionList.map(dim => item[dim]).join('-'))
                   .mapValues(group => _.map(group, measure))
                   .value()
        }
      )
    });
```

Example data and the expected results

```js
[
    {
        "day": "2024-01-01",
        "city": "A",
        "category": "X",
        "order": 100,
        "buyer": 50,
        "gmv": 1000
    },
    {
        "day": "2024-01-01",
        "city": "A",
        "category": "Y",
        "order": 110,
        "buyer": 160,
        "gmv": 1200
    },
    {
        "day": "2024-01-02",
        "city": "A",
        "category": "X",
        "order": 125,
        "buyer": 60,
        "gmv": 1400
    },
    ...
]
```

```js
[
    {
        "day": "2024-01-01",
        "city": "A",
        "category": "X",
        "order": [100,null,null]
        "buyer": [50,null,null]
        "gmv": [1000,null,null]
    },
    {
        "day": "2024-01-01",
        "city": "A",
        "category": "Y",
        "order": [110,null,null]
        "buyer": [160,null,null]
        "gmv": [1200,null,null]
    },
    {
        "day": "2024-01-02",
        "city": "A",
        "category": "X",
        "order": [125,25,0.25]
        "buyer": [60,10,0.2]
        "gmv": [1400,400,0.4]
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: can you show calculation of rollup values for the last item in the result array? for example it's not clear why it's [125,25,.25]

Comment: The 125 is the value of {"city":"A","category": "X"} of "day": "2024-01-02". So its previous value is 120 of "day": "2024-01-01" with the same properties {"city": A, "category": "X"}. Day in "YYYY-MM-DD" format btw. So  curr = 125, prev=120, #diff= 25, %diff =25/120=0.25

Comment: it's 120, on 01-02, 125-120=5, not 25

Comment: Yeah, sorry. The raw data should be 100 and 125. I cannot edit my comment but I already edited my post.  Pls refer to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the array with `Array.map()`, and use a `Map` to hold the previous item with the same dimensions. On each item take the previous from the `Map` (or default `null`), and replace it with the current item. Return the new object after calculating the diffs.

```js
const { mapValues, pick } = _;

const dimensionList = ["city","category"];
const measureList = ["order","buyer","gmv"];

const getDimensions = item => dimensionList.map(dim => item[dim]).join('-');

const getMeasures = (curr, prev) => prev === null 
  ? [curr, null, null]
  : [curr, curr - prev, (curr - prev) / prev];
  
const updateItem = (curr, prev) => ({
  ...curr,
  ...mapValues(pick(curr, measureList), (v, k) => 
    getMeasures(v, prev?.[k] ?? null)
  )
});

const mapDiffs = arr => {
  const dimMap = new Map();

  return arr.map(item => {
    const dimensions = getDimensions(item);
    
    const prev = dimMap.get(dimensions) ?? null; 
    
    dimMap.set(dimensions, item);
    
    return updateItem(item, prev);
  });
};

const arr = [{"day":"2024-01-01","city":"A","category":"X","order":100,"buyer":50,"gmv":1000},{"day":"2024-01-01","city":"A","category":"Y","order":110,"buyer":160,"gmv":1200},{"day":"2024-01-02","city":"A","category":"X","order":125,"buyer":60,"gmv":1400}];

const result = mapDiffs(arr);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```